# В каких случаях совместное использование cin и scanf может привести к ошибке?

Tags: c++

Считается плохим тоном использовать С и С++ функции чтения потока в одной программе. Но тем не менее ранее это никогда не приводило к ошибкам.

Совсем недавно, решая [задачу](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/LASTDIG2/), в которой нужно последовательно читать `int` и `char[]` столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Если читаем:

1. `int` через `scanf`, а `char[]` через `cin`
2. `int` через `cin`, а `char[]` через `scanf`

то это приводит к неправильному ответу. Если же оба параметра считываем одинаковой функцией, то решение проходит.

Поэтому возник вопрос: при каких ситуациях возможны конфликты между этими функциями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы делаете что-то неправильно. По умолчанию библиотеки ввода вывода C и C++ синхронизированы, поэтому можно безопасно чередовать использование функций из одной и другой библиотеки.
Синхронизацию можно включить-выключить явно, используя функцию `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`.

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам!

У меня синхронизация была выключена в целью увеличения быстродействия cin'а.

Comment: >У меня синхронизация была выключена в целью увеличения быстродействия cin'а.

 Интересно, зачем cin'у быстродействие? Пользователь вводит данные в миллион раз дольше, чем нужно времени на их обработку cin'ом.

Comment: а если перенаправление данных  с файла? для утилит типа grep.

Comment: GLMonster: Через пайп могут какие угодно данные идти